# Stuck "Flagged posts" indication?

Tags: bug

There's the yellow "pending flags" indicator, but this is what appears on the "flagged posts" page:

[image]

Sometimes there actually are some flagged posts to be dealt with, at other times none, but that indication remains there for various periods, sometimes a day, with no evident means of getting rid of it.

No harm done, but it is distracting, and causes time to be wasted in clicking that link.

Bug, or as-designed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that rawbrawb's answer is correct and this is a side-effect of the top bar count still including flags that you acted on. I also vaguely recall us trying to fix that at one point. I'll have to follow up with the devs to see what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

These are flags that you have acted on but have not been processed or flagged to completion by others.  Look in the right hand column and there will be a count of flags that you have operated on like this:
[image]

Comment: If he has already acted it should not be there.

Comment: Yup: I've always acted on any flag the moment I spot it, so that shouldn't be it - but it is, hence the bug report.

Comment: @Kortuk Now it's even more FUBAR, the yellow dot count is out of sync with the list of flags.